# Merge 2 maps with keys as values of second map

Tags: java, kotlin, dictionary, merge

I have 2 maps defined as `Map<String, Set<String>>` :

```text
map1 : {
   Honda=[Accord, Civic, CRV], 
   Toyota=[Corola, RAV4, Yaris]
}
map2 : {
   Accord=[5w30, 10w40],
   Civic=[0w30, 5w30, 5w40],
   CRV=[5w30, 5w40, 10w40],
   Corola=[0w30, 10w40], 
   RAV4=[0w20, 0w30, 5w30]
}
```

I need merge this 2 maps so the result map key will be brand name (e.g. Honda, Toyota) and values will be all of oils. Some like this:

```text
mergeMap: {
   Honda=[0w30, 5w30, 5w40, 10w40],
   Toyota=[0w20, 0w30, 5w30, 10w40]
}
```

---

I wrote sam old school method which use `forEach` blocks, but I think that it can be better using streams and so on. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the resulting map will have the same keys, you can use [`mapValues`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-values.html).

In the lambda, [`flatMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map.html) each of the strings in the values set to the corresponding value in the second map, if it exists.

```
map1.mapValues { (_, v) -> v.flatMap { map2[it] ?: emptyList() }.toSortedSet() }
```

This gives you a `Map<String, SortedSet<String>>`.

Note that this will sort the “0w30” strings lexicographically, as they are strings, so you won’t get the exact order you want. I don’t know what these strings represent, but you should probably represent them with a data class implementing `Comparable` instead. That’d give you the correct order.

Comment: I would apply _distinct()_ and _sorted()_ after the _flatMap { }_

Comment: @lukas.j oh I didn’t realise that detail! How about [`toSortedSet`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-sorted-set.html)?

Comment: even better, didn't think of that.